# git filter clean/smudge changes are not reflecting in local while its in repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

.git/config

```
[filter "file-cleanup"]
    clean = sed -e 's/deeptesh/changed-deeptesh/g'
    smudge = cat
```

.gitattributes

```
*.sh filter=file-cleanup
```

This change is working fine. this is replacing deeptesh with changed-deeptesh and when committing, the changes are reflecting in the repo. But, the problem is either after committing, pushing, pulling, checkout the file, reindexing, the rewrite changes are not reflecting in the local editor. The only way its reflecting is by deleting the file in the local and checkout the file again from the remote repo.

Comment: This is by design. The clean filter only keeps the repository contents clean, not the working files.